# Emacs Is Auto-Escaping Periods From The Command Line

Tags: microsoft-windows, eval, batch-mode

I'm attempting to run the `profile-dotemacs.el` script from the command line using Powershell on Windows. Here's what I'm trying to run

```
 emacs -Q -l C:\users\tom\Downloads\profile-dotemacs.el --eval "(setq profile-dotemacs-file `"~/.emacs.d/emacs-init.el`")" -f profile-dotemacs
```

I'm using the backtick mark to escape the quotation marks, which is the standard in Powershell.

When Emacs starts up I get the following error:

```
eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: ~/\.emacs\.d/emacs-init\.el
```

I don't believe this is a Powershell issue because I'm getting the same issue when I try to run the command from the Windows cmd prompt (i.e. not using Powershell).

For some reason Emacs seems to be auto-escaping my periods. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Emacs thinks `~/.emacs.d/emacs-init.el` is a variable, not a string. Can't you use single quotes for the `--eval` and then unescaped double quotes inside them? (I'm powershell ignorant)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @nega. Yes, I am able to do that but I get the same results.